# Presenting multiple views in SwiftUI using .navigationDestination(isPresented:) - views won't pop back

Tags: swiftui

I'm having an issue presenting a series of views in SwiftUI using buttons (not the default navigation back button). It should be relatively simple, each view is presenting a child using `.navigationDestination(isPresented:...)`.

The child gets a reference to the `isPresented` of the previous controller via `@Binding` and set that to false. For the simple example: [fwd, back] this works. But if we push several views [fwd, fwd, fwd, back] the view won't pop.

Somehow the default back button works. So I feel like either I'm doing something wrong with how I am passing the binding, or that using that `.navigationDestination(isPresented:...)` does not work with multiple views.

Code here (that runs in a SwiftUI preview):

```
/// works: fwd, back, fwd, back. (result: end on step 1)
/// fail: fwd, fwd, back. (result: stays on step 3, should be step 2).
import SwiftUI

struct StepView: View {

    @State var counter = 0

    /// Holds the previous screens presentation
    /// Changing to false will pop this view.
    @Binding var previous: Bool

    /// Controls whether to present the next screen
    /// for this current screen.
    @State var isPresented: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Step \(self.counter)")
            Button {
                self.isPresented = true
            } label: {
                Text("Forward")
            }
            Button {
                self.previous = false
            } label: {
                Text("Back")
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle("Step \(self.counter)")
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        .navigationDestination(
            isPresented: $isPresented
        ) {
            StepView(
                counter: self.counter + 1,
                previous: $isPresented
            )
        }
    }
}

struct StepView_Previews: PreviewProvider {

    @State static var test = false

    static var previews: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            StepView(previous: self.$test)
        }
    }
}
```